# Connection Timed Out + SSL Connection + TCPIP + Indy10.5.5

Tags: delphi, openssl, delphi-2010, indy

I am developed one application for sending files client to server using TCP/IP Components using SSL.

Error is **Connection Timed Out** is occurred when Sending Large Files **at Server Side**

Server Side (SSL)

```
   idTCPServer1.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
   OnExecute
      Acontext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      Acontext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(filestream,Filesize);  // Error is occurred here.
   End;
```

Client Side (SSL)

```
   idTCPClient1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
   idTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
   idTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteStream(fms,-1,True);
```

Connection is established between Client & Server. When send the files after some time Connection Timed out is error is shown at server & at client application going to Not Responding .

Here another scenario is when i connect the Client & Server as Normal using IdIOHandlerStack1 (at Client Side) and server side not assign any Handler. Files transfered successfully with out any problem.

I am using Delphi2010 & Indy10.5.5, DLL Version is 0.9.8.18

anyone guide to me

Answer (score 0):

There is no `WriteStream()` method, there is a `TStream` overload of the `Write()` method instead.

You are telling `Write()` to send the stream size as a 64-bit integer, but you are not telling `ReadStream()` to read the stream size, so presumably you have read the full 64-bit file size beforehand using `ReadInt64()`, correct?

Also, 10.5.5 is an outdated version of Indy.  The current version is 10.5.9.  [Try upgrading](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) to make sure you have all of the latest bug fixes and such, and then report back if you are still having problems.

Comment: By mistakely i mentioned wrong statement at Client (WriteStream). First of all i am Sending the Actual File Size from Client. This is not mentioned in above code. After getting the File Size at Server I write the code like this `Acontext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(filestream,Filesize);`. At Client idTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(tempStream,-1,True)

Comment: FileSize is an Int64 datatype only

Comment: I download Indy10.5.9 from (https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10/). When i try to Compile of System140.dproj of Indy 10.5.9 into Delphi2010. This is not Compiled due to following errors Undeclared identifier **LONG** (at 1851 Line), in `{$EXTERNALSYM _RIORESULT}
  _RIORESULT = record
    Status : **LONG**;
    BytesTransferred : ULONG;
    SocketContext : ULONGLONG;
    RequestContext : ULONGLONG;
  end; ` declaration) and **PVOID** (at line 2627), in ` _RIO_NOTIFICATION_COMPLETION_IOCP = record
    IocpHandle : THANDLE;
    CompletionKey : **PVOID**;
    Overlapped : **PVOID**;
  end; `

Comment: "First of all i am Sending the Actual File Size from Client" - are you doing that manually? Because you are telling `Write()` to send the file size by setting its `AWriteByteCount` parameter to True, so are you actually sending the file size twice? `ReadStream()` has the ability to read the file size for you (in fact, that is its default behavior) so you don't have to do it manually.  `IOHandler.Write(fms, 0, True)` and `IOHandler.ReadStream(filestream, -1, False)`.

Comment: There are no `_RIO...` types declared in Indy. What file is complaining about them? It can't be an Indy file.

Comment: Mentioned above code exsited in IdWinsock2.pas unit in IndySystem140.dproj Package. Indy 10.5.9 Version downloaded from the Path (https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10/). There is no 10.5.9 version available under **Tags**. So i am download from NextGen folder.

Comment: 10.5.9 hasn't been tagged in SVN yet. There is no `RIO` code in `IdWinsock2.pas` in the current public version of 10.5.9. Stay away from the NextGen code, it is not for public use yet. It is new code being developed for a new compiler we are supporting. If you are going to download from SVN directly, download the Trunk code only, not the Branch code. Or download a nightly snapshot from the [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com) instead.

Comment: For 10.5.8 or 10.5.9. what Version of DLL(libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll) are required for SSL. Presently i am using 0.9.8.18. If latest dlls are required. Can you give the path for it.

Comment: Indy 10 uses the official OpenSSL DLLs as-is, so just use the latest available, which you can download from [OpenSSL's website](http://www.openssl.org) or Indy's [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).